# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny' in django application

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

Error in browser console:

```
 Refused to display 'http://74.207.232.194/media/edas/881063.html?&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

My backend url http://74.207.232.194 which is a django application.

In side my django application some html files is there inside media folder.

I am trying to access and embel the htmls from backend media folder to my react.js application.

But, It is not working with above error.

Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the value in your django settings by using:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM http://74.207.232.194'
```

Also it would be a good idea to use a Content Security Policy

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors 'self' 74.207.232.194 *.74.207.232.194;
```